# Handle ASP.Net internal thread pool which process the requests

Tags: asp.net, .net, multithreading, threadpool

My undersatnding on ASP.Net is when a request comes, ASP.Net uses a internal thread from thread pool to do the work and respond. Correct me if I am wrong. If that is the case, will I able to get a control on this asp.net thread pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot interact with the thread pool directly though. However, you can manipulate some of the characteristics of the thread pool by setting the [processModel in your web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge that information is not available to your application.

What is it you are trying to accomplish?